# Problem in maintaining state in IceFaces

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0, icefaces

I am using EJB-3 & IceFaces in my application on JBoss.
On refreshing the page, the data gets lost & all fields becomes blank.

In another similar application where struts is used, no such problem occurs.
Is this problem with IceFaces(View-handler/Render-response etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is typical when the HTTP request concerns a GET request and the bean is request scoped. The struts application was apparently using a session scoped bean.

Comment: In Struts+EJB application, in request scoped bean also, values remains as it was before refreshing page.

In application built with only IceFaces, there is no problem.

But I am using here IceFaces+EJB3, not getting any clue about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain data through a page refresh in request scope then something is wrong with your program logic.

By its very nature request scope would only have available to it data within that scope .. which means that the data is lost each time a new request is made.

Is the other application you are referring to adding something into the request scope when it constructs the request?

Comment: No, there is no problem on refresh in application built only in IceFaces, but fields become blank in another application built in IceFcaes+EJB-3. Both have similar strucure for view layer.